# FTP timeout to web host

Tags: ftp, firewall, filezilla, web-hosting

Macbook pro 10.9.5

regular web host (cPanel)

router firewall set to low

machine firewall off

proper login credentials

Filezilla/Cyberduck

Telnet to 198.252.106.222 21 does not connect

FTP connection still timing out.

What to do?

Comment: can you ping it? I can ftp to it [rejected for no password, of course, but at least it's a solid rejection]

Comment: I figured it out. The FTP client transfer settings needs to be set to "passive". However, not all FTP clients gave me the option to adjust transfer settings so I'm not sure if it's a fix for all occurrences of this problem.